PyNaCl Build Failure on Solaris 10: randombytes Test Fails During make check
I am trying to build and install PyNaCl on a Solaris 10 (SunOS 5.10) system, but the process fails during the make check step. The failure occurs in the randombytes test, which results in the overall test suite failing with a non-zero exit status.
Environment:
•   OS: Solaris 10 (SunOS 5.10)
•   Architecture: x86_64
•   GCC Version: 9.5.0
•   Python Version: 3.11
•   PyNaCl Version: 1.4.0
•   libsodium Version: 1.0.18


PASS: aead_aes256gcm
PASS: aead_aes256gcm2
PASS: aead_chacha20poly1305
...
FAIL: randombytes
...
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for libsodium 1.0.18
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 77
# PASS:  76
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  1
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
See test/default/test-suite.log
Please report to https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues
============================================================================
make[4]: *** [Makefile:1776: test-suite.log] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/PyNaCl-1.4.0/build/temp.solaris-2.10-i86pc.64bit-cpython-311/test/default'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1884: check-TESTS] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/PyNaCl-1.4.0/build/temp.solaris-2.10-i86pc.64bit-cpython-311/test/default'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:2490: check-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/PyNaCl-1.4.0/build/temp.solaris-2.10-i86pc.64bit-cpython-311/test/default'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:402: check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/PyNaCl-1.4.0/build/temp.solaris-2.10-i86pc.64bit-cpython-311/test'
make: *** [Makefile:514: check-recursive] Error 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/PyNaCl-1.4.0/setup.py", line 216, in <module>
    setup(
  ...
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make', 'check']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

cd /usr/local/src
wget https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz
tar -xzvf libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz
cd libsodium-1.0.18
./configure 
make
make install

cd /usr/local/src
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/P/PyNaCl/PyNaCl-1.4.0.tar.gz
tar xzf PyNaCl-1.4.0.tar.gz
cd PyNaCl-1.4.0
sed -i '/subprocess.check_call(\["make", "check"\] /s/^/#/' setup.py
/opt/infinidat/toolkit/bin/python setup.py build
/opt/infinidat/toolkit/bin/python setup.py install


See test/default/test-suite.log?  So what's in test/default/test-suite.log?
